# Matplotlib how to move axis along data in a real-time animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to plot data that is generated in runtime. In order to do so I'm using `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`.

While the data is displayed correctly, the axis values are not updating accordingly to the values that are being displayed:

[image: graph animation]

The x axis displays values from 0 to 10 eventhough I update them in every iteration in the `update_line` function (see code below).

`DataSource` contains the data vector and appends values at runtime, and also returns the indexes of the values being returned:

```py
import numpy as np

class DataSource:
    data = []
    display = 10

    # Append one random number and return last 10 values
    def getData(self):
        self.data.append(np.random.rand(1)[0])
        if(len(self.data) <= self.display):
            return self.data
        else:
            return self.data[-self.display:]

    # Return the index of the last 10 values
    def getIndexVector(self):
        if(len(self.data) <= self.display):
            return list(range(len(self.data)))

        else:
            return list(range(len(self.data)))[-self.display:]
```

I've obtained the `plot_animation` function from the *matplotlib* docs.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datasource import DataSource


def update_line(num, source, line):
    data = source.getData()
    indexs = source.getIndexVector()
    if indexs[0] != 0:
        plt.xlim(indexs[0], indexs[-1])
        dim=np.arange(indexs[0],indexs[-1],1)
        plt.xticks(dim)
    line.set_data(indexs,data)
    return line,

def plot_animation():
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    source = DataSource()

    l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')

    plt.xlim(0, 10)
    plt.ylim(0, 1)
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.title('test')
    line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, fargs=(source, l),
                                    interval=150, blit=True)

    # To save the animation, use the command: line_ani.save('lines.mp4')


    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_animation()
```

How can I update the x axis values in every iteration of the animation?

(I appreciate suggestions to improve the code if you see any mistakes, eventhough they might not be related to the question).

Comment: Is it correct that the data set for the graph in the animation function is out of the IF function, I thought so because I set `plt.xlim(indexes,data)` in the IF function.

Comment: The graph displays 10 values. The IF statement ensures (or at least i want it to ensure) that the axis is only updated once there are more than 10 values in the set, so it has to "move" to the right.

Comment: I actually got the code to work. Since the data we are drawing is less than 1.0, I think we can handle it by adding the following after the dataset for the graph.　`line.set_data(indexs,data);plt.xlim(indexs[0], indexs[-1])`

Comment: We would be setting the xlim to (1,1) at the first iteration, since there would be only one element in the dataset. That answer is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

My problem was in the following line:

```py
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, fargs=(source, l),
                                    interval=150, blit=True)
```

What I had to do is change the `blit` parameter to `False` and the x axis started to move as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple case of how you can achieve this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

#data generator
data = np.random.random((100,))

#setup figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

#rolling window size
repeat_length = 25

ax.set_xlim([0,repeat_length])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])


#set figure to be modified
im, = ax.plot([], [])

def func(n):
    im.set_xdata(np.arange(n))
    im.set_ydata(data[0:n])
    if n>repeat_length:
        lim = ax.set_xlim(n-repeat_length, n)
    else:
        lim = ax.set_xlim(0,repeat_length)
    return im

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=data.shape[0], interval=30, blit=False)

plt.show()

#ani.save('animation.gif',writer='pillow', fps=30)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my problem was the `blit` option in the `FuncAnimation` line, the axis wasn't moving because I had that set to `True`. The rest of my code was fine.

Comment: cool, glad to have helped. good to see you figured out the code modification required! As you can see, I also showcase `blit=False` in my answer as well, along with rolling window modifications.

Comment: Yeah, definetely noticed it thanks to your answer, upvoted for the help :)